# So i created a Callback function in React and i am invoking it but it keeps in showing the error that its undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

```
import React from 'react';


state = {language : 'english'};

onLanguageChange = (language) =>{
    this.setState({language});
}

render(){
    return (
        <Context.Provider value ={{...this.state, onLanguageChange }}>
            {this.props.children}
        </Context.Provider>
    );
}
```

}

So the error is in `OnLanguageChange` and it shows that it is `undefined`:

> src\contexts\LanguaugeContext.js   Line 15:55:  'onLanguageChange' is
> not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to be a class field - that means that it's a property of the instance, not a standalone variable, so you can't use a shorthand property name with it.

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { language: 'english' };

  onLanguageChange = (language) => {
    this.setState({ language });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{ ...this.state, onLanguageChange: this.onLanguageChange }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its really helpful